# How to scroll to a particular section of the data fetched from an API while filtering the data on some parameter?

Tags: reactjs, filter, jsx, display

I am calling an API from a server, and I am getting this as a response. A part of the data I am getting -

```
{
    "id": 322854,
    "date": "2022-09-20T18:00:00+00:00",
    "time": "18:00",
    "timestamp": 1663696800,
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "stage": null,
    "week": null,
    "status": {
        "long": "Game Finished",
        "short": "FT",
        "timer": null
    },
    "league": {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "French Cup",
        "type": "cup",
        "season": 2022,
        "logo": "https://media-2.api-sports.io/basketball/leagues/9.png"
    },
    "country": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "France",
        "code": "FR",
        "flag": "https://media-2.api-sports.io/flags/fr.svg"
    },
    "teams": {
        "home": {
            "id": 22,
            "name": "Boulazac",
            "logo": "https://media-2.api-sports.io/basketball/teams/22.png"
        },
        "away": {
            "id": 2294,
            "name": "CEP Lorient",
            "logo": "https://media-2.api-sports.io/basketball/teams/2294.png"
        }
    },
    "scores": {
        "home": {
            "quarter_1": 16,
            "quarter_2": 12,
            "quarter_3": 21,
            "quarter_4": 26,
            "over_time": null,
            "total": 75
        },
        "away": {
            "quarter_1": 9,
            "quarter_2": 16,
            "quarter_3": 19,
            "quarter_4": 23,
            "over_time": null,
            "total": 67
        }
    }
}
{
    "id": 322854,
    "date": "2022-09-20T18:00:00+00:00",
    "time": "18:00",
    "timestamp": 1663696800,
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "stage": null,
    "week": null,
    "status": {
        "long": "Game Not Started",
        "short": "NS",
        "timer": null
    },
    "league": {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "French Cup",
        "type": "cup",
        "season": 2022,
        "logo": "https://media-2.api-sports.io/basketball/leagues/9.png"
    },
    "country": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "France",
        "code": "FR",
        "flag": "https://media-2.api-sports.io/flags/fr.svg"
    },
    "teams": {
        "home": {
            "id": 22,
            "name": "Boulazac",
            "logo": "https://media-2.api-sports.io/basketball/teams/22.png"
        },
        "away": {
            "id": 2294,
            "name": "CEP Lorient",
            "logo": "https://media-2.api-sports.io/basketball/teams/2294.png"
        }
    },
    "scores": {
        "home": {
            "quarter_1": 16,
            "quarter_2": 12,
            "quarter_3": 21,
            "quarter_4": 26,
            "over_time": null,
            "total": 75
        },
        "away": {
            "quarter_1": 9,
            "quarter_2": 16,
            "quarter_3": 19,
            "quarter_4": 23,
            "over_time": null,
            "total": 67
        }
    }
}
```

There are a bunch of such objects in an array each having a different fixture. As you can see that `status?.short === "NS"` in one while the other is `status?.short === "FT"`. Now, I want to filter the data using these properties.

```
    <div className="fixturesTab-container">
      <div className="fixturesTab-container__header">
        <h4>Fixtures</h4>
      </div>
      <div className="fixturesTab-container__body">
        {fixtures.map((fixture) => (
            <div
              key={fixture?.id}
              className="fixturesTab-container__body__box"
            >
              ......
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want the data to be displayed in such a manner that when the user browse to that page and the API is being fetched, eventhough the entire data (fixtures) is being displayed in the page. I want the fixtures that have not yet started, i.e has the property of `status?.short === "NS"`, to be displayed in the window that is visible to the user. And the rest data can be acquired by either scrolling up, which will have the fixtures that have been completed, or by scrolling down which will have the fixtures that have not yet been started.

If, I am unable to understand what I want properly, then you can check out this [page](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1JJTC_enIN959IN959&sxsrf=ALiCzsZO2Xa2J9LNGVEN7fpyCMdI0evqPQ:1671042881996&q=la+liga+fixtures&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi83orr3_n7AhXX9XMBHQLYDf8QBSgAegQIBxAB&biw=1707&bih=828&dpr=1.13#sie=lg;/g/11sqj24s0_;2;/m/09gqx;mt;fp;1;;;) . This is exactly what I am planning to achieve.

Comment: Are we talking about `sorting` the data on `status?.short` ?

Comment: I can sort the data from the `filter` method in javascript, that's not an issue. I actually want to display that sorted data in such a way that `status?.short === "NS"` (all the matches that have not yet been started) be displayed in the screen view the user is currently in, and in order to access the matches that have all ready been played, he has to scroll up.